# Button inside Vuetify's text-field append slot clicking through

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create Vuetify's `v-text-field` with slot named `append` and the slot contains button. Everything is working fine except the fact that my click clicks through button and focuses `text-field` and on mobile opening keyboard.

This is my text-field component

```
<v-text-field
    class="search-input"
    solo
    hide-details
    rounded
    elevation-12
    :placeholder="searchFieldPlaceholder"
    aria-label="Search"
    @input="searchDidChange"
  >
    <slot slot="append" name="end" />
</v-text-field>
```

This is my button, which contains the `@click.stop` when I call my text-field component out

```
<template v-slot:end>
    <v-btn
      text
      icon
      class="ml-2"
      aria-label="List view"
      @click.stop="gridView = !gridView"
    >
      <v-icon>view_list</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</template>
```

My question is how should I stop the button to propagate inside `v-text-field`? I also tried `@click.native` and the effect is the same. The documentation also mentioned about `@click:append` but this will break my component slot logic and then I should start using predefined props which is not what I want.

Comment: Isn't your `v-btn` inside the `v-text-field`?

Comment: This this case i think you're forced to use `append-outer` if you don't want the input focus. Without hacking a solution.

Comment: Can you refer to where Vuetify does it them selfs? In their `slot` example, their `append` is doing the exact same as yours

Comment: They're both showing with usage of the `props` and with `slots`. With the `props` the input won't get focused, but with the `slots` it does exactly the same behavior as yours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the code you're showing, you can skip all the `slot` usage, and use in `append` and `@click:append`

So your code would looks like this:

```
<v-text-field
       class="search-input"
       solo
       hide-details
       rounded
       elevation-12
       :placeholder="searchFieldPlaceholder"
       aria-label="Search"
       @input="searchDidChange"
       append-icon="view_list"
       @click:append="gridView = !gridView"
/>
```

Not recommended, but a hacked way to not make the

Change your `@click` to do the following:

```
$refs.searchInput.blur(), gridView = !gridView
```

And add the following to the `v-text-field`

```
ref="searchInput"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `@click:append=""` in your `v-text-field`